# Guidance needed on using CADisplayLink with tableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, progress-bar

I am creating an app that contains lists which will be valid for a certain amount of time. For that I am creating a countdown bar animation on each cell. Each cell has it's own custom duration after which the cell displays "Time's Up". The cell even shows the time in seconds as it ticks down to 0 and then displays "Time's Up" message.

Right above this, there is a countdown bar animation. I am controlling all these animations from the viewController and not doing these in the customView cell as cell reusability makes the timers go haywire.

I am using two timers:

1. `Timer()` : that invokes every 1 second. This is used for the simple seconds countdown. I am using an array of type struct that houses two variables `durationTime` & `width`. The `width` is set to 400 by default. The `durationTime` is set by the user.

   ```
   @objc func handleCountdown() {
   let arrayLength = duration.count
   var i: Int = 0
   var timeCount: Int = 0


   for  _ in 0..<arrayLength {


      let value = duration[i].durationTime - 1 //Decreasing the timer every second
      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)


       if (value > 0)
       {
           duration[i].durationTime = value
           if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell? {
               cell.testlabel.text = "\(value)"
           }
           //listTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
           i = i + 1
       } else {
           if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell? {
               cell.testlabel.text = "Time's Up"
           }
           i = i + 1
           timeCount = timeCount + 1

       }
   }

   if (timeCount == (arrayLength - 1)) {
       self.timer?.invalidate()
   }
   }
   ```

The above code is invoked every second. It decrements the value of the time, and then displays it in the tableview cell. The above code works fine as it should.

2. `CADisplayLink`: this timer is used to run the progress bar animation. In this case however, I am calculating the elapsed time and dividing it by the durationTime of each element and calculating a percentage. This percentage is used to update the value of `width` of each progress bar. (Keep in mind that durationBar is simply duplicate of duration array. In this array however, the durationTime is not being decremented -> Just for testing purposes)  Here is the code:

   ```
   @objc func handleProgressAnimation() {
   let currenttime = Date()
   let elapsed = currenttime.timeIntervalSince(animationStartDate)
   let totalWidth: Double = 400.0
   print(elapsed)
   let arrayLength = duration.count
   var i: Int = 0



   for  _ in 0..<arrayLength {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
      let percentage = (elapsed / Double(durationBar[i].durationTime))
      let newWidth = Double(totalWidth - (totalWidth * percentage))
       durationBar[i].width = newWidth
       if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell? {
           cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(durationBar[indexPath.row].width)

       }
       i = i + 1
   }

   }
   ```

**Question**: After some time, some progress bars just disappear from the cells even though the time has not been completed. It occurs most often once I have done some scrolling on the tableview.

This is `willDisplayCell` & `cellForRowIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let cell:listTableViewCell = cell as! listTableViewCell
    cell.testlabel.text = "\(duration[indexPath.row].durationTime)"
    cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(duration[indexPath.row].width)

}
```

As you can in pictures below, after sometime, some progress bars vanished even though there is still some time left:

[image]

What is the issue here, I am controlling all the animations and timers from the viewController and not the cell in order to prevent cell reuseability to become a problem. Help is needed!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you update `cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width` with

`durationBar[indexPath.row].width` for `handleProgressAnimation` and

`duration[indexPath.row].width` for `willDisplayCell`.

And also I would switch to tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows for updating UI only for visible cells so it wouldn't call .cellForRow for every cell in if-let.

Comment: And there'll be probably no difference if you move willDisplayCell code to cellForRow.

Comment: I changed it from duration to durationBar but still there is ambiguity and the progress bar disappear after some scrolling and time. In if-let statements I am just picking the cell at the particular indexPath to be updated. Don't find the need to switch to visibleRows. Is there any issue with the CADisplayLink timer? The countdown seems to work fine.

Comment: @OsamaNaeem if the issue is occuring after scrolling - look into methods of tableView. As I mentioned: willDisplayCell and cellForRowAt. Also I'm not sure how you reuse your cells (perpareForReuse).

Comment: I am not using the prepareForReuse method anywhere in the custom cell and the methods in the tableview are already posted above. It's a pretty weird bug. Any other option?

Comment: I guess I know the reason now. The progress bar vanishes mainly when one of the cell time is completed. This means that the view's width becomes 0. The cell which is reused then most probably has the same width and therefore it causes issue. I used prepareForReuse() method to set the width of the bar back to 400 before the cell is reused but that doesn't seem to work. :/